# How do I set an attr_accessor for a dynamic instance variable?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, attr, attr-accessor

I dynamically created an instance variable within my class:

```
class Mine
  attr_accessor :some_var

  def intialize
    @some_var = true
  end

  def my_number num
    self.instance_variable_set "@my_#{num}", num
  end
end
```

How do I make `@my_#{num}` now as an attr value?

e.g. I want to be able to do this:

```
dude = Mine.new
dude.my_number 1
dude.my_1
=> 1
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

this answer doesn't pollutes the class space, example.. if i do `mine.my_number 4` then the other instances of `Mine` will not get the `my_4` method.. this happens because we use the singleton class of the object instead of the class.

```
class Mine
  def my_number num
    singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor "my_#{num}" }
    send("my_#{num}=", num)
  end
end

a = Mine.new
b = Mine.new
a.my_number 10 #=> 10
a.my_10 #=> 10
b.my_10 #=> NoMethodError
```

Comment: Is there a reason using `singleton_class`? Also being a one-liner, `class_eval { attr_accessor :"my_#{num}" }` syntax would be cleaner :)

Comment: @HalilÖzgür you want to define that method only for that instance, so that's why you use `singleton_class`, if you use `self.class`, then all instances get the method and you don't want that.

you are right with the syntax, I'll make the change

Comment: btw singleton_class is the same as doing `class << self`

Comment: I mean the above code produces the same output without `singleton_class`.

Comment: @HalilÖzgür `class_eval` is a class method, not an instance method

Comment: oh, sorry! I was confusing something else with this, interestingly it seemed to display the same result for once.

Answer (score 25):

This can be accomplished using `__send__`.  Here:

```
class Mine
  attr_accessor :some_var

  def intialize
    @some_var = true
  end

  def my_number num
    self.class.__send__(:attr_accessor, "my_#{num}")
    self.__send__("my_#{num}=", num)
  end
end

dude = Mine.new
dude.my_number 1
puts dude.my_1

=> 1
```

Comment: This will define accessors on all instances, not just the one you called `my_number` on. I added an additional answer that only adds methods for the instances you added an instance variable for.

Answer (score 10):

Easy. You can dynamically define the attribute reader inside the my_number method:

```
  def my_number num
     self.instance_variable_set "@my_#{num}", num
     self.class.class_eval do
        define_method("my_#{num}") { num }
     end
  end
```

see if that works for you

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use OpenStruct:

```
require "ostruct"

class Mine < OpenStruct
end

dude = Mine.new
dude.my_number = 1
dude.my_number # => 1
```

I don't know why you'd want `dude.my_1` to return 1 - isn't that giving you back what you already have?

Comment: I'm curious how you could inherit OpenStruct *and* ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: @Trip you can't inherit from multiple classes.

Answer (score 4):

There's one problem with the two methods here... if an instance variable is set in one instance, its accessor will be available to all instances, because you're defining methods on `self.class` instead of on self.

```
dude = Mine.new
dude.my_number 1
puts dude.my_1
dudette = Mine.new
dudette.my_1 = 2    # works, but probably shouldn't
dudette.my_number 2
dude.my_2 = 3       # works, but probably shouldn't
```

What you probably want to do is modify only the instance that has the instance variable:

```
class Mine
  # ...
  def my_number num
    class << self
      attr_accessor "my_#{num}"
    end
    self.send("my_#{num}=", num)
  end
end
```

This way, instance variables only get accessors on the objects they were created for. I also didn't bother with instance_variable_set, because if you're setting an accessor, then I think it reads better to just reuse that. But that's a style call. The big deal here is calling `class << self` instead of `self.class`.

Comment: When I tried this I got the error "undefined local variable or method `num' for #<Class:#<Mine:...>". Seems that the num variable falls out of scope here.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I'll have to think about this a bit more. In the meantime, this is not the right solution. :/

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Delete your answer if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution to add to the pile, [`define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method):

```
class Mine
  def my_number num
    define_singleton_method("num_#{num}") { num }
  end
end
```

One side effect of all of these solutions is that if you call it multiple times with different numbers, you end up with a bunch of methods on your object:

```
dude = Mine.new
dude.my_number 1
dude.my_number 5
dude.my_1
=> 1
dude.my_5
=> 5
```

We can fix this by removing the old method:

```
class Mine
  def my_number num
    old_num = @num
    if @num
      # need to use `old_num` local variable
      # instance var scope is different inside `class_eval`
      singleton_class.class_eval { remove_method("num_#{old_num}") }
    end

    @num = num

    define_singleton_method("num_#{num}") { @num }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

older thread, but I found it useful thank you.  Here is the code Dorkus Prime's answer, but also taking instance vars from name\values in a hash

```
@cookies = browser.cookies.to_a

@cookies.each do |cookie|
self.class.__send__(:attr_accessor, "#{cookie[:name]}")
self.__send__("#{cookie[:name]}=",cookie[:value])
end
```