# Access JSONB fields as normal ActiveRecord attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonb

I have a column on my model User called properties which is jsonb. As i have the requirement for user generated dynamic fields.

How would you access the attributes as if they were normal mapped columns

E.g
User model has a column called first_name but a property in the properties called eye_color

```
user = User.find(1)
user.first_name # => "john"
# to access the eye color you would do
user.properties['eye_color'] # => "green"
```

What I would like to do is to be able to call the map json attribute so i can set and get it via like bellow

```
user.eye_color = 'green'
```

This needs to be dynamically done as the field attributes can change. However, at the user instance I can see work out what all the attributes will be.

Comment: I made something for this that _might_ solve your problem. https://github.com/joshmn/setsy

Comment: [Another possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18815753/4988918) in addition to @joshbrody...I'd ask why you need this functionality if the keys are dynamic though...you won't know ahead of time (assumingly) what the keys are...so why not just use `user.properties['eye_color']`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try overriding `method_missing` on your `User` model

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  clean_method = method.to_s.chomp('=')

  if properties.key?(clean_method)
    if method.to_s.ends_with?('=')
      return properties[clean_method] = args.first
    else
      return properties[clean_method]
    end
  end

  super
end
```

This should allow you to get and set directly

```
# set value
user.eye_color = 'green'

# get value
user.eye_color # => returns 'green'
```

Comment: How would you suggest you map back the datatype? i.e. if what you pass is a datetime when you call the method name it parses into a datetime

Comment: I'm not sure. In your jsonb field, numbers will be saved as numbers and anything else will be saved as a string. How are you originally getting the fields? Are users selecting the datatype of the field at the time of input?

Comment: Yes the user would chose the datatype. eg time, dattime, text, decimal, etc

Comment: Sorry @JakeMcAllister I totally lost track of this. Were you able to figure out a solution to your problem?