# dynamic attributes in Rails ActiveRecord store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming, accessor

I have a child model, which should be able to store different attributes via the ActiveRecord::Store feature. Those attributes should be determined by the parent model. For this purpose, the parent model has a column `content_attributes` which stores the children's attributes as array of strings (i.e. `['color', 'size', 'age']`).

To have accessors in the child instances for all attributes defined by the parent, i currently use a workaround which maps all attribute names of all available parents:

```
class child
  belongs_to :parent

  store :content, accessors: Parent.all_content_attributes, coder: JSON
  ...
end
```

Actually, i only want to set accessor's for all attributes of the distinct parent. However, in the example above, the child instance would get a long list of dispensable attribute names.  How to replace the `Parent.all_content_attributes`? Guess i need some kind of metaprogramming here?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
  store :content_store, coder: JSON

  after_initialize :add_accessors_for_content_attributes

  def add_accessors_for_content_attributes
    content_attributes.each do |attr_name|
      singleton_class.class_eval do
        store_accessor :content_store, attr_name
      end
    end
  end

  def content_attributes
    parent.content_attributes.map(&:name)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, essentially you need to perform a database lookup for the parent `content_attributes` upon instantiation of your child object, and then assign the accessors dynamically based on that data.

Something along these lines could work - [How do I set an attr_accessor for a dynamic instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964179/how-do-i-set-an-attr-accessor-for-a-dynamic-instance-variable)

You could try an `after_initialize` callback that does the lookup and then calls [`store_accessor`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) on the singleton class.

Comment: Isn't it a problem, that i have to define the accessors during or before initialization, since i already need those during initialization, i.e. Child.new(color:...)? But anyways, i will give it a try!